# Unable to find element with id : Issue only when executing on IE. Works fine for Firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

My Code is as below:

```
package ie;

import java.io.File;



import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class ieproject{

 public static void main(String[] args) { 

  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS );
  try
  {
  driver.get("http://demo.actitime.com");
  driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");

  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  driver.quit();
 }

}
```

## Am getting exception while running the same:

Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.43.0.0
Listening on port 35578
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See /logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == username (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 15.22 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: /seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.43.0', revision: '597b76b', time: '2014-09-09 20:52:14'
System info: host: 'AJITKUMAR-PC', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_20'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: 892cecb0-ba03-48f6-a29e-7eb7c56da813
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
    at ie.ieproject.main(ieproject.java:28)

Comment: I hope the page does not take more than 15 seconds to load in the Internet Explorer browser.

Comment: Would be nice if the stacktrace was formatted a little nicer, but found this in the statemnt: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == username` - is the element with id of username on the page for IE?

Answer (score 0):

I have troubles with IE11 and Selenium too - sometimes web driver couldn't find an element but in other browsers (chrome, firefox) all works fine for same tests.

I found this solution: you need to create (if it is not exists) registry key -
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE` and `DWORD` value in it with name `iexplore.exe` and value data 0.

For x64 systems - do the same with key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`